# Strip all spaces from a variable and append to another variable if not blank

Tags: makefile

I'm using make in Windows and I need to manipulate some variables to create a filename. I have a base filename and an optional part to append. If the optional part is appended an underscore should be inserted between two parts. The optional part is being read in from a file and contains 5 characters (spaces or alphanumeric).

This is what I expected to work:

```
OPTIONAL_NAME="     "
BASE_NAME=myfile
STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME=$(strip $(OPTIONAL_NAME))
ifeq ("$(STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME)","")
FULL_NAME=$(BASE_NAME)
else
FULL_NAME=$(BASE_NAME)_$(STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME)
endif
```

OPTIONAL_NAME could have the following values:

```
OPTIONAL_NAME="     "
OPTIONAL_NAME="ABCDE"
OPTIONAL_NAME="A    "
OPTIONAL_NAME="  A  "
OPTIONAL_NAME="    A"
```

The value of OPTIONAL_NAME has quotes around it due to the way it is being imported (see my previous question - [Read a value from a file into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180162/read-a-value-from-a-file-into-a-variable)).

The problem with the result is that `strip` seems to reduce multiple spaces to single spaces, but not actually remove leading or trailing spaces.

I've tried using this to strip the spaces:

```
space:=
space+=
STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME=$(subst $(space),,$(OPTIONAL_NAME))
```

This does remove the spaces, but I struggle to check for an empty string.

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put the variable in the comparison in quotation marks. Try this instead:

```
ifeq ($(STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME),"")
```

The above checks for empty strings.

Or

```
ifeq ($(STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME)," ")
```

to check for single space.

Comment: Hi Joachim, Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. If `OPTIONAL_NAME="     "` then `ifeq ($(STRIPPED_OPTIONAL_NAME),)` resolves as false. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my environment that is causing this?